# Customizable javascript chart build for high performance

Tags: javascript, linegraph, pitch, pitch-tracking

I want to create a piece of software in the browser that listens to microphone and detects it's pitch region. Then I want to show it on realtime streamed line graph. On yAxis there will be mapped MIDI keys presenting the notes (under the hood - yAxis will be just Hz), and on x axis I want to show the line based on Hz.

I already have built something that listens to the microphone and detects frequencies in Hz in realtime. The website is written in React. Now I need to use some library chart that will update the line with the pitch value. If there is no such value (nobody singing/speaking), the chart will be filled with nulls or missed values.

Is there any chart library that is focused to has high performance with strong customization options? I tried apache/echarts, but it seems that it has trobule with streaming in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively try [LightningChartJS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/). We have multiple charts which can be used for audio visualization in real-time. These charts feature strong customization options as well as the ability to place multiple charts into a dashboard-like layout.

Have a look at our [Interactive Examples](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/) and more specifically, the [audio visualization example](https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-audio/) too.

I am a LightningChart Dev, so if you need any support, feel free to message me.